# React Native 0.69.5 White Screen Crash

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I had react native 0.68.2 project for update I created new react project then installed expo bareworkflow add all packages 1 by 1 after adding babel and other configs now I cannot make it work. Either IOS nor Android. Most of the time code errors with AppName not registered.

Android /build.gradle

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
    
    if (System.properties['os.arch'] == "aarch64") {
        // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
        ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
    } else {
        // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
    }
}
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1")
    classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
    classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:5.0.1")
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
 *   // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
 *   // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and that value will be read here. If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

/**
 * Architectures to build native code for.
 */
def reactNativeArchitectures() {
    def value = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeArchitectures")
    return value ? value.split(",") : ["armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64", "arm64-v8a"]
}

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.social"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.7"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED", isNewArchitectureEnabled().toString()
        multiDexEnabled true

        if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
            // We configure the NDK build only if you decide to opt-in for the New Architecture.
            externalNativeBuild {
                ndkBuild {
                    arguments "APP_PLATFORM=android-21",
                        "APP_STL=c++_shared",
                        "NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang",
                        "GENERATED_SRC_DIR=$buildDir/generated/source",
                        "PROJECT_BUILD_DIR=$buildDir",
                        "REACT_ANDROID_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid",
                        "REACT_ANDROID_BUILD_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/build",
                        "NODE_MODULES_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules"
                    cFlags "-Wall", "-Werror", "-fexceptions", "-frtti", "-DWITH_INSPECTOR=1"
                    cppFlags "-std=c++17"
                    // Make sure this target name is the same you specify inside the
                    // src/main/jni/Android.mk file for the `LOCAL_MODULE` variable.
                    targets "myapp_appmodules"
                }
            }
            if (!enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture) {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters (*reactNativeArchitectures())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
        // We configure the NDK build only if you decide to opt-in for the New Architecture.
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                path "$projectDir/src/main/jni/Android.mk"
            }
        }
        def reactAndroidProjectDir = project(':ReactAndroid').projectDir
        def packageReactNdkDebugLibs = tasks.register("packageReactNdkDebugLibs", Copy) {
            dependsOn(":ReactAndroid:packageReactNdkDebugLibsForBuck")
            from("$reactAndroidProjectDir/src/main/jni/prebuilt/lib")
            into("$buildDir/react-ndk/exported")
        }
        def packageReactNdkReleaseLibs = tasks.register("packageReactNdkReleaseLibs", Copy) {
            dependsOn(":ReactAndroid:packageReactNdkReleaseLibsForBuck")
            from("$reactAndroidProjectDir/src/main/jni/prebuilt/lib")
            into("$buildDir/react-ndk/exported")
        }
        afterEvaluate {
            // If you wish to add a custom TurboModule or component locally,
            // you should uncomment this line.
            // preBuild.dependsOn("generateCodegenArtifactsFromSchema")
            preDebugBuild.dependsOn(packageReactNdkDebugLibs)
            preReleaseBuild.dependsOn(packageReactNdkReleaseLibs)

            // Due to a bug inside AGP, we have to explicitly set a dependency
            // between configureNdkBuild* tasks and the preBuild tasks.
            // This can be removed once this is solved: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/207403732
            configureNdkBuildRelease.dependsOn(preReleaseBuild)
            configureNdkBuildDebug.dependsOn(preDebugBuild)
            reactNativeArchitectures().each { architecture ->
                tasks.findByName("configureNdkBuildDebug[${architecture}]")?.configure {
                    dependsOn("preDebugBuild")
                }
                tasks.findByName("configureNdkBuildRelease[${architecture}]")?.configure {
                    dependsOn("preReleaseBuild")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include (*reactNativeArchitectures())
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            // Example: versionCode 1 will generate 1001 for armeabi-v7a, 1002 for x86, etc.
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])

    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine:+") { // From node_modules
            exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
        }
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
    // If new architecture is enabled, we let you build RN from source
    // Otherwise we fallback to a prebuilt .aar bundled in the NPM package.
    // This will be applied to all the imported transtitive dependency.
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
            substitute(module("com.facebook.react:react-native"))
                    .using(project(":ReactAndroid"))
                    .because("On New Architecture we're building React Native from source")
            substitute(module("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine"))
                    .using(project(":ReactAndroid:hermes-engine"))
                    .because("On New Architecture we're building Hermes from source")
        }
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.implementation
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

def isNewArchitectureEnabled() {
    // To opt-in for the New Architecture, you can either:
    // - Set `newArchEnabled` to true inside the `gradle.properties` file
    // - Invoke gradle with `-newArchEnabled=true`
    // - Set an environment variable `ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_newArchEnabled=true`
    return project.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && project.newArchEnabled == "true"
}
```

proguard-rules.pro

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.3.3/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:
-keep class com.facebook.hermes.unicode.** { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.jni.** { *; }
-keep class com.swmansion.reanimated.** { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.react.turbomodule.** { *; }
-keep public class com.dylanvann.fastimage.* {*;}
-keep public class com.dylanvann.fastimage.** {*;}
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.myapp.social">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
      <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
      <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="myapikey"/>
      <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="https://exp.host/@myname/myapp"/>
      <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="46.0.0"/>
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Some of LogCat Results

```
2022-09-05 14:13:07.348 13579-13579/? E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so

2022-09-05 14:13:07.382 13579-13579/? E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes-executor-debug.so

2022-09-05 14:13:07.960 403-524/? E/HWComposer: getSupportedContentTypes: getSupportedContentTypes failed for display 4619827259835644672: Unsupported (8)

2022-09-05 14:13:10.532 13579-13718/? E/ReactNativeJS: Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
          This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
2022-09-05 14:13:10.546 13579-13719/? E/unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule: Unhandled SoftException
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Catalyst Instance has already disappeared: requested by DeviceInfo

2022-09-05 14:13:10.753 13579-13662/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: expo-updates-error-recovery
    Process: com.myapp.social, PID: 13579
    com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Invariant Violation: ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'., js engine: hermes,
```

On XCode this the error
[image]

Answer (score -2):

For more files :

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    plugins: [
      [
        'module-resolver',
        {
          root: ['./src'],
          extensions: [
            '.ios.js',
            '.android.js',
            '.js',
            '.ts',
            '.tsx',
            '.json',
            '.svg',
            '.png',
            '.jpg',
          ],
          alias: {
            '@Components': './src/components',
            '@Assets': './assets',
            '@Screens': './src/screens',
            '@Declarations': './src/declarations',
            '@Services': './src/services',
            '@Utils': './src/utils',
            '@Hooks': './src/hooks',
            '@Helpers': './src/helpers',
            '@Store': './src/store',
            '@Routes': './src/routes',
          },
        },
      ],
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ],
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "1.0.7",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4",
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.2.2",
    "@notifee/react-native": "^5.6.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.10",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^4.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^15.4.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^15.4.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "^15.4.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^15.4.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^15.4.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^15.4.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^8.0.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.7",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.3",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.4",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.2.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.12",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.8.0",
    "@types/react-combine-reducers": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.5",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "chroma-js": "^2.4.2",
    "expo": "^46.0.0",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~10.4.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~13.3.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-linking": "~3.2.2",
    "expo-localization": "~13.1.0",
    "expo-location": "~14.3.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.14.5",
    "expo-video-thumbnails": "~6.4.0",
    "i18next": "^21.9.1",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.10.13",
    "lottie-ios": "^3.4.3",
    "lottie-react-native": "^5.1.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.37",
    "numbro": "^2.3.6",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-combine-reducers": "^1.1.1",
    "react-countdown": "^2.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.18.5",
    "react-native": "0.69.5",
    "react-native-3dcube-navigation-typescript": "^1.0.24",
    "react-native-agora": "^3.7.1",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-better-image": "^0.0.3",
    "react-native-collapsible-tab-view": "^4.5.2",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^7.3.0",
    "react-native-expo-viewport-units": "^0.0.8",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.0",
    "react-native-fbsdk-next": "^10.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-image-modal": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.1.12",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-markdown-display": "^7.0.0-alpha.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^5.4.25",
    "react-native-picker-modal-view": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-purchases": "^5.0.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.10.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.17.0",
    "react-native-skeleton-placeholder": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.1.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-tags": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-video": "6.0.0-alpha.1",
    "victory-native": "^36.6.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.69.5",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.29.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.29.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.70.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

tsconfig

```
    // prettier-ignore
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json",     /* Recommended React Native TSConfig base */
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@Components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "@Screens/*": ["src/screens/*"],
      "@Declarations/*": ["src/declarations/*"],
      "@Services/*": ["src/services/*"],
      "@Assets/*": ["assets/*"],
      "@Utils/*": ["src/utils/*"],
      "@Hooks/*": ["src/hooks/*"],
      "@Helpers/*": ["src/helpers/*"],
      "@Store/*": ["src/store/*"],
      "@Routes/*": ["src/routes/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "__tests__"]
}
```

app.json

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "displayName": "MyApp",
  "expo": {
    "name": "MyApp",
    "slug": "MyApp",
    "sdkVersion": "46.0.0",
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "assets/fonts/*.ttf",
      "assets/images/*.svg",
      "assets/images/*.png",
      "assets/images/*.jpg",
      "assets/json/*.json",
      "assets/translations/*.json",
      "**/*"
    ],
    "packagerOpts": {
      "sourceExts": [
        "expo.ts",
        "expo.tsx",
        "expo.js",
        "expo.jsx",
        "ts",
        "tsx",
        "js",
        "jsx",
        "json",
        "wasm",
        "svg",
        "png",
        "jpg"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Podfile

```
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '13.0'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

production = ENV["PRODUCTION"] == "1"

target 'MyApp' do
  $static_framework = []
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'
  pod 'RNPurchases', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-purchases', :inhibit_warnings => true

  use_expo_modules!

  $static_framework += [
    'react-native-maps',
    'react-native-google-maps',
    'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils',
    'GoogleMaps'
  ]

  post_integrate do |installer|
    begin
      expo_patch_react_imports!(installer)
    rescue => e
      Pod::UI.warn e
    end
  end
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :production => production,
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    #:flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.enabled,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  pre_install do |installer|
    Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, :verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}
        installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
            if $static_framework.include?(pod.name)
                def pod.build_type;
                Pod::BuildType.static_library # >= 1.9
            end
        end
    end
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```